# How to create C# odata V4 entity relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I created a odata v4 project using visual studio 2015 with "EF Designer From Database"

I got 2 entity and they are sql-view i created from microsoft sql server 2015,

i can get the data with simply odata uri
localhost:post/odata/BookingInfoes('BookingId') or
localhsot:post/odata/Timemarkers('BookingId')

My question is one BookingInfo  relate to many timemarker items and 
i couldnt use the command ?$expand, i tried many approach in google but still no luck,

i want something like

```
{BookingID:123,BookingDate:"sss",[TimeMarker:[{id:1,info:"sss"},{id:2,info:"balh bla"},{id:3,info:"foo foof oo"}]]}
```

please help, this stuck me a week and i have no idea how to deal with.

entiy BookingInfo

```
namespace wcod.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class BookingInfo
    {
        public BookingInfo()
        {
            var TimeMarkerList = new List<TimeMarker>();
        }
        public string BookingID { get; set; }
        public string BookingDate { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string ChiBookName { get; set; }
        public string VideoSource_1500 { get; set; }
        public string VideoSource_300 { get; set; }
        public string VideoSource_Archive { get; set; }
        public string MobileVideoSource { get; set; }
        public string languages { get; set; }
        public string SeekTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IsVideo { get; set; }
        public string AvailableLangs { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StatusMarkers { get; set; }
        public string BookRoomID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> nexturl { get; set; }
        public string StrBookingStartTime { get; set; }
        public string BookomgStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TimeMarker> TimeMarkers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TimeMarker also generated from sql-view

```
    namespace wcod.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TimeMarker
    {
        public Nullable<long> nrow { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OrderNo { get; set; }
        public string MeetingID { get; set; }
        public string AgendaName { get; set; }
        public string ChiAgendaName { get; set; }
        public int AgendaCode { get; set; }
        public string AgendaTime { get; set; }
        public string SpeakerCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> MarkerID { get; set; }
        public string AgendaRunningTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> AllLangFail { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isLive { get; set; }
        public string PopUpMsg { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> HasVideo { get; set; }
        public string TimeMarkerId { get; set; }

        public virtual BookingInfo BookingInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
using wcod3.Models;

namespace wcod3
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            // var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;          
            builder.EntitySet<TimeMarker>("TimeMarkers");
            builder.EntitySet<MeetingInfo>("BookingInfoes");

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }


            );

            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/v4", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my BookingsController

heres is the TimeMarkersController

```
  [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<TimeMarker> GetTimeMarkers()
    {
        return db.TimeMarkers;
    }

    // GET: odata/TimeMarkers(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public List<TimeMarker> GetTimeMarker([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        // return SingleResult.Create(db.TimeMarkers.Where(timeMarker => timeMarker.MeetingID == key));
        // return List
        return db.TimeMarkers.Where(timeMarker => timeMarker.MeetingID == key).ToList() ;

    }
    public List<MeetingInfo> GetMeetingInfo([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        return db.MeetingInfoes.Where(mi => mi.MeetingID == key).ToList();
    }
```

and packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>






http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/TimeMarkers('id')/?$expand=BookingInfo
http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/TimeMarkers('id')?$expand=BookingInfo
http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/MeetingInfoes('id')/?$expand=TimeMarkers
http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/MeetingInfoes('id')?$expand=TimeMarkers
```

above all 4 url show parent content only, i really want they show together. 
please help.

Comment: I realise this is old, however for this type of question it is important that you post the $metadata document, that explains the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I finally get the job done,

I generate the Entities using EF designer
Using the GUI to create the relation with the Model.Edmx and right click
any model you want to create relation and select add association
left the "add foreign key properties to the 'entityName' Entity"

*if you auto update the model, all annotation virtual class will disappear and i don't know why, and finally i get the relation done

```
http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/BookingInfoes('key')?$expand=TimeMarkers
```

the package.config for your reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never use odata with sql-view, but i think you need to add some information to you model: there is not explicit relation between BookingInfo and TimeMarker.

Try to add to the View TimeMaker an an explicit reference to BookingInfo (ex. BookingInfoId) and also to entity TimeMaker :

```
public partial class TimeMarker
{
    public Nullable<long> nrow { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string MeetingID { get; set; }
    public string AgendaName { get; set; }
    public string ChiAgendaName { get; set; }
    public int AgendaCode { get; set; }
    public string AgendaTime { get; set; }
    public string SpeakerCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MarkerID { get; set; }
    public string AgendaRunningTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> AllLangFail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isLive { get; set; }
    public string PopUpMsg { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> HasVideo { get; set; }

    public int BookingInfoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BookingInfoId ")]
    public virtual BookingInfo BookingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then set BookingInfo as Inverse Property of TimeMarkers:

```
public partial class BookingInfo
{
    [Required]
    public string BookingID { get; set; }
    public string BookingDate { get; set; }
    public string MeetName { get; set; }
    public string ChiMeetName { get; set; }
    public string VideoSource_1500 { get; set; }        
    public string languages { get; set; }        
    public string AvailableLangs { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StatusMarkers { get; set; }
    public string MeetRoomID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> nexturl { get; set; }
    public string StrBookingStartTime { get; set; }
    public string MeetomgStatus { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("BookingInfo")]
    public virtual ICollection<TimeMarker> TimeMarkers { get; set; }

}
```

Sorry, I can't try but I hope this help you.

Comment: tried http://localhost:port/odata/v4/BookingInfoes('xxxx') but only BookingInfo show, no timeMarker display then i tried followed this[http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx] still nothing

Comment: Did you try localhost:port/odata/v4/BookingInfoes('xxxx')?$expand=TimeMarkers ? If you don't add $expand in querystring, it's correct you see only BookingInfo

Comment: It is not necessary to set `InversePropertyAttribute` for simple relationships like this, it wont hurt, but it also is not likely to help OP in this case

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` should have correctly defined your EdmModel, in the future you can confirm this by inspecting (and posting into SO) the $metadata response, this you can see via the standard url:

`http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/$metadata`

---

#### Background Theory

In OData Controllers, you can either manually prepare the structured data response or you can let the `EnableQueryAttribute` manage this all for you. To get the full benefit from `EnableQueryAttribute` you need to return a `IQueryable<T>` response from your endpoint method.

- For endpoints that return a single item, you can use the `SingleResult` response helper function to return an `IQueryable<T>` that you expect to only return a single record.
- If you choose **NOT** to return an `IQueryable<T>` response from your method, then the `EnableQueryAttribute` can still evaluate the query options, but it can only evaluate them against the information that has been provided.

So what is happening when the response is a fixed object or list, but not a query against the database, is that `EnableQueryAttribute` creates a query against the response object an the query options are applied only to that query instance.

> As a general rule, **NEVER** `.ToList()` the queries in your controller implementations!

OK, so *never* is a bit extreme, but know that if you are calling `.ToList()` or you have otherwise eagerly loaded the query into a local variable, then the `EnableQueryAttribute` can only work with the data that is already in memory.

So if you do **NOT** want to return an `IQueryable<T>` or you have eagerly loaded, then you must remember to include *all* of the navigation properties that you want to allow your clients to `$expand` on.

---

#### Implementation

You didn't actually include your `BookingsController` implementation, but I'm sure it is in the same style of the `TimeMarkersController`

Because your initial `GetBookings()` and `GetTimeMarkers()` are returning an `IQueryable<T>` correctly, and they are adorned with the `[EnableQuery]` attribute, the following URLs with expansions should work:

All Bookings:
`http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/BookingInfoes?$expand=TimeMarkers`

Single Booking:
`http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/BookingInfoes?$expand=TimeMarkers&$filter=BookingID`

> If expansion using the above queries does NOT work, then make sure your EdmModel is correctly defined.

The two following variations of `GetBookingInfo` should both expand correctly, the first version is the simplest, it simply passes through the raw DB query, there are no restrictions in this case on which navigation properties will be supported.

```
// GET: odata/BookingInfoes(123)
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetBookingInfo([FromODataUri] string key)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(db.BookingInfoes.Where(b => b.BookingID == key));
}
```

Or if you want to specifically limit the navigation options, in this case the *ONLY* expansion that will be allowed is on `TimeMarkers` because it is the only data that has been read from the database. You may also have other reasons to eagerly load or otherwise  the data record, we can do so like this:

```
// GET: odata/BookingInfoes(123)
[EnableQuery]
public BookingInfo GetBookingInfo([FromODataUri] string key)
{
    var booking = db.BookingInfoes.Include(b => b.TimeMarkers)
                                  .Where(b => b.BookingID == key)
                                  .Single();
    // TODO: other processing...
    return booking;
}
```

The following URL will work for both of these:
`http://localhost:49347/odata/v4/MeetingInfoes('id')?$expand=TimeMarkers`